# How to have two different models within a route and its subroute?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm making a simple web chat system with Ember.

I have a route `/chatrooms` that lists a few chatrooms, and then I also have `/chatrooms/:chatroom_id` that should show the actual chatroom with messages.

The second route is within the first one, like this:

```
this.resource('chatrooms', function() {
  this.route('show', {
    path: ':chatroom_id'
  });
});
```

When I access `/chatrooms`, a call is made to the server (`/api/chatrooms`) is a list of rooms is returned and displayed, like expected.

When I click a room, the application transitions to `/chatrooms/id`, but no call is made to retrieve the messages (available at `/api/chatrooms/id`), even when I try to define a model.

I have a similar scenario with the users. A list of users is retrieved, then displayed. When a name is clicked, the profile is shown. No second call is made, but that's okay since Ember knows everything about the user already.

In my current case, when a list is first returned, it includes all the information except the messages. I believe that would be too much otherwise (10 chatrooms * 100 last messages = 1000 elements in my JSON for each request). So I want to call the server for messages only when a chatroom is selected.

Do you know how to do it, or maybe there's something wrong I'm doing in the first place?

**Updates**

Template code from `app/templates/chatrooms.hbs`

```
<h1>Chatrooms</h1>
<ul class="sub-menu nobullet flex mas">
    {{#each chatroom in model}}
        <li class="mrs">{{link-to chatroom.name "chatrooms.show" chatroom class="pat"}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

In this case, model is an array of chatrooms.

My routes:

app/routes/chatrooms.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('chatroom');
  }
});
```

app/routes/chatrooms/show.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.get('chatroom', params.chatroom_id);
  },
  actions: {
    send: function() {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the template code where you link to a room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a links property to the JSON response for chatrooms. When the content of a chatroom has to be displayed, the link is used and the messages retrieved. It only requires two requests, and there's not need to preload all the messages from all the chatrooms and no need to make a request for each message.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/why-is-it-not-possible-to-trigger-the-model-hook-via-link-to-helper/3984/3), when you `link-to` a route and the model is already loaded, the `model` hook of the route is not fired because there’s no need to reload the data.

> If you transition to a route and **all** the context objects -the objects which will serve as models to templates- are passed in, the `beforeModel` and `model` hooks will not be called.

Later in the thread balint [corrects](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/why-is-it-not-possible-to-trigger-the-model-hook-via-link-to-helper/3984/6):

> In fact, the `beforeModel` hook still gets called in that case, it is only the model hook that does not.

If you want to force the model to be reloaded, you can change your link to use the ID instead of the model:

```
{{link-to chatroom.name "chatrooms.show" chatroom.id class="pat"}}
```

You could also load the data in the `beforeModel` or `afterModel` hooks, or `setupController`.

---

Also, in the `chatrooms/show` route, you are getting the already-loaded model from the Ember Data store rather than loading it from the server. Try this:

```
return this.store.find('chatroom', params.chatroom_id);
```

Comment: I changed `chatroom` for `chatroom.id`, but I still get the same problem. Even when I reload my app and directly access `/chatrooms/1`, the messages or not called. When I remove the `model` hook in the  upper route, I simply don't get a list of rooms anymore, and there's still no call made for the messages.

Comment: Okay, I added more to the answer. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Still doesn't work.
I just read this: http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/05/01/why-ember-data-breaks.html
Is it possible that Ember Data is not the right tool for my problem? What worries me is this part:
"if you're loading a hasMany relationship from a model, that model will need to have a list of all the IDs for the relationship's resources - there's no way to load only a subset of a few IDs and add more later"
This is going to add a lot of code to my code if I want to fix this. And it will probably be inefficient. I think I should just make some AJAX calls... (but it's almost 2 years old...)

Comment: This might apply to your use-case: http://watsonbox.github.io/blog/2014/06/13/lazy-and-partial-data-loading-with-ember-dot-js-and-rails/